# Combine two xml files and remove duplicate elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to concat two xml files while removing entries with duplicate names (even if values are different) using xsl. Please see example files. Thanks a lot for your help.

File1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<archive>
  <entry>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>123</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <value>456</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>zzz</name>
    <value>789</value>
  </entry>
</archive>
```

File2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<archive>
  <entry>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>2468</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>ttt</name>
    <value>13579</value>
  </entry>
</archive>
```

The resulting file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<archive>
  <entry>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>123</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <value>456</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>zzz</name>
    <value>789</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>ttt</name>
    <value>13579</value>
  </entry>
</archive>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDoc1" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/file1.xml')"/>
 <xsl:param name="pDoc2" select="document('file:///c:/temp/delete/file2.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$pDoc1/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <archive>
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="$pDoc2/*/entry[not(name = current()/*/name)]"/>
  </archive>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied on any XML document (not used) and having the files with this content (as provided):

c:\temp\delete\file1.xml

```
<archive>
  <entry>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>123</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>yyy</name>
    <value>456</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>zzz</name>
    <value>789</value>
  </entry>
</archive>
```

c:\temp\delete\file2.xml

```
<archive>
  <entry>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <value>2468</value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <name>ttt</name>
    <value>13579</value>
  </entry>
</archive>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<archive>
   <entry>
      <name>xxx</name>
      <value>123</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <name>yyy</name>
      <value>456</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <name>zzz</name>
      <value>789</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <name>ttt</name>
      <value>13579</value>
   </entry>
</archive>
```