# Add node in XML file with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

How can I merge two XML files in an output XML file with XSL?
For example, we have

File 1 :

```
<tests>
     <test name="testOne"/>
     <test name="testTwo"/>
     <test name="testThree"/>
     <test name="testFour"/>
</tests>
```

File 2 :

```
<tests>
     <test name="testOne"/>
     <test name="testTwo"/>
     <test name="testThree"/>
     <test name="testFour"/>
     <test name="testFive"/>
</tests>
```

The output file must be :

```
<tests>
 <test name="testOne"/>
 <test name="testTwo"/>
 <test name="testThree"/>
 <test name="testFour"/>
 <test name="testFive"/>
</tests>
```

Example 2 with the same XSL :
File 1 :

```
<tests>
     <test name="testOne"/>
     <test name="testTwo"/>
     <test name="testThree"/>
     <test name="testFour"/>
</tests>
```

File 2 (bis) :

```
<tests>
     <test name="testFive"/>
</tests>
```

Output file :

```
<tests>
 <test name="testOne"/>
 <test name="testTwo"/>
 <test name="testThree"/>
 <test name="test4"/>
 <test name="testFive"/>
</tests>
```

For the output file, i want all the information contained in the two xml files. I'm novice in XSL, this is an example to help me. Thank

Comment: And you tried to do what?

Comment: Did you search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981381/combine-two-xml-files-and-remove-duplicate-elements

Comment: Your example does not disclose the logic of the required operation.

Comment: Websearching for "xslt merge" will find multiple solutions. One resource that more people should be aware of is Dave Pawson's XSL FAQ page, at http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/. Dave collected many of the best answers from the XSL Users' Mailing List, and this page includes solutions for many XSL tasks from basic to sophisticated to "I didn't think that was possible".